# A question on $C^*$ algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $0\leq x\leq a$ for $x,a\in B(H)$ for some complex Hilbert space $H.$ Then we know that there exists a contraction $u$ such that $x^{1/2}=ua^{1/2}.$ Now if we know that $x,a\in A$ where $A\subset B(H)$ for some $C^*$ algebra $A$ can we also say that $u$ can be chosen in $A$?

Comment: Is the identity operator $1 \in A$?

Comment: Yes. I assume $A$ is unital.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not always. For example, let $A=C([-1,1])$, $x(t)=t_+^2$ and $a(t)=t^2$. If there were $u\in C([0,1])$ such that $x^{1/2}=ua^{1/2}$, we would have $u(t)=0$ for $t<0$ and $u(t)=1$ for $t>0$. Clearly there is no continuous function with these properties.

Comment: @ MaoWao. But if $A$ is a von Neumann algebra then should it be alright?

Comment: Yes. This is explained in this article, for example: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.04378.pdf.